# Calculation returning wrong resutls

Tags: nested, tableau-api, calculation

I am created a calculation using two calculationsi n Tableau   The results returned are incorrect.  But each piece of the calculation returns the correct number.

**Cal 1:**

`If YEAR([TRANSACTION_DATE ) = YEAR(TODAY())  AND [TRANSACTION_DATE (Custom SQL Query)]< TODAY()  THEN [Handled] END`

**Results: 57,619**

**Cal 2:**

```
`If YEAR([TRANSACTION_DATE (Custom SQL Query)]) = YEAR(TODAY()) 
    AND [TRANSACTION_DATE (Custom SQL Query)]< TODAY() 
    and [Contact Type His]= 'CHAT Agt' THEN [AS ACTIVE TIME (S)]/3600
    ELSEIF YEAR([TRANSACTION_DATE (Custom SQL Query)]) = YEAR(TODAY())  
    AND [TRANSACTION_DATE (Custom SQL Query)]< TODAY() 
    and[Contact Type His]  = 'BLENDED Agt' Then [Busy Time (S)]/3600 end`
```

**Results:  6,012**

**Final Calculation:** `CAL 1 /CAL 2`
**Results** 20997.79 expecting   9.58

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are the results shown aggregated at full data level or some other level?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate these aggregations without any further level of detail, use this calculation

`COL1`

```
{SUM(
If YEAR([TRANSACTION_DATE ) = YEAR(TODAY())  AND [TRANSACTION_DATE (Custom SQL Query)]< TODAY()  THEN [Handled] END
)}
```

`COL2`

```
{SUM(
If YEAR([TRANSACTION_DATE (Custom SQL Query)]) = YEAR(TODAY()) 
    AND [TRANSACTION_DATE (Custom SQL Query)]< TODAY() 
    and [Contact Type His]= 'CHAT Agt' THEN [AS ACTIVE TIME (S)]/3600
    ELSEIF YEAR([TRANSACTION_DATE (Custom SQL Query)]) = YEAR(TODAY())  
    AND [TRANSACTION_DATE (Custom SQL Query)]< TODAY() 
    and[Contact Type His]  = 'BLENDED Agt' Then [Busy Time (S)]/3600 end
)}
```

and then `Col1/Col2`